# How to check if a form field is filled with just number in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I tried with

```
@Min(value=1)
@Max(value=30)  
private int lunghezza;
```

If I filled the form field with a String, I get this error:

```
    Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
 type int for property lunghezza; nested exception is 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "21jkh"
```

I don't understand if I have to use another `@Annotation`, or if it already works and I just have to customize some messagge in .properties files.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100590/validate-numbers-in-spring

Comment: Did you bother to read the exception text? It does just what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you man. I already used typeMismatch but it didn't work to me, since I've not registered its file properties in the "basenames" of my MessageSource Class. Now it works